# Ffmpeg invalid data when trying to merge videos

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have a below function for merging videos in Python without re-encoding using FFmpeg:

```
def merge():
    """
    This function merges a group of videos into one long video.
    It is used for merging parts that are cut from original video into a new one.
    The videos are merged using ffmpeg and for the ffmpeg
    to use the concat method on them, the video names must be put inside
    the vidlist.txt file.
    New video is saved to the file named output.mp4.
    """
    command = "ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -f concat -safe 0 -i vidlist.txt -c copy output.mp4"
    # merge multiple parts of the video
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

I store paths to videos to be merged inside a vidlist.txt file which looks like:

```
file 'out11.mp4'
file 'out21.mp4'
```

But, I am getting the following error:

```
vidlist.txt: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Here is the report file:

```
ffmpeg started on 2020-07-30 at 20:23:53
Report written to "ffmpeg-20200730-202353.log"
Log level: 48
Command line:
ffmpeg -hide_banner -f concat -safe 0 -i "C:\\Users\\miliv\\videocutter\\utils\\vidlist.txt" -c copy output.mp4 -report
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-hide_banner' ... matched as option 'hide_banner' (do not show program banner) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'concat'.
Reading option '-safe' ... matched as AVOption 'safe' with argument '0'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'C:\Users\miliv\videocutter\utils\vidlist.txt'.
Reading option '-c' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option 'output.mp4' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option hide_banner (do not show program banner) with argument 1.
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url C:\Users\miliv\videocutter\utils\vidlist.txt.
Applying option f (force format) with argument concat.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: C:\Users\miliv\videocutter\utils\vidlist.txt.
[concat @ 000001aaafb8e400] Opening 'C:\Users\miliv\videocutter\utils\vidlist.txt' for reading
[file @ 000001aaafb8f500] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 000001aaafb97700] Statistics: 0 bytes read, 0 seeks
C:\Users\miliv\videocutter\utils\vidlist.txt: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share report file.

Comment: I've added it in question

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was trying to merge video before closing the vidlist.txt file which then didn't allow ffmpeg to open it